# Convert mysql database to sqlite database using shell script

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have shell script. I want to convert mysql database to sqlite database. 
I want to install cygwin. 
Can anybody help in getting what packages i need to install ?

I tries a lot's but if i select all then it takes whole day and nothing happen or sometime it breaks installation.